# C# giving different value than expected

Tags: c#

I just started to learn C# and I faced this problem:
The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test_CSharp_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
            double num = Console.Read();
            
            Console.WriteLine("Result = " + num*num);
            
        }        
        
    }
}
```

When i give the input: 10
this is the output:

```
Enter the number:
10
Result = 2401
Press any key to continue . . .
```

pls help.

I use Visual Studio 2019 (community edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Console.Read()` gives you the next character value (i.e: it gives you a valid `char` value or -1), not the value of the next input number.

Instead you must use `Console.ReadLine()` and parse it with `double.TryParse(string, out double)`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
// Get the next line input
string input = Console.ReadLine();
// Try to parse it as a double
if (double.TryParse(input, out double num)) {
    // On true we have a number
    Console.WriteLine("Result = " + num*num);
} else {
    // On fail we couldn't parse it.
    Console.WriteLine("Error, please input a number.");
}
```

Comment: To elaborate a tad: it's reading the character value of the `1` that was entered, so OP is getting 49 * 49.